# objective C parameter and declaration

Tags: objective-c

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef struct{
    float exchangeRate;
    float theBudget;
    float euroTransaction;
}budget;
budget vacationBudget;
budget vacationBudgetEngland;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vacationBudget.exchangeRate=1.2500;
    vacationBudget.theBudget=1000.00;
    double numberDollars=100;
    double numberEuros=100;
```

2nd qs-For the two lines below ERROR GIVEN : Implicit declaration of function spendDollar and chargeEuros. Invalid in C99. What does implicit declaration mean?

```
    spendDollar(numberDollars);
    NSLog(@"converting %.2f US dollars from a budget of 1000 into euros leaves %.2f",numberDollars,vacationBudget.theBudget);
    chargeEuros(numberEuros);
    NSLog(@"cnverting %.2f euros leaces %.2f",numberEuros,vacationBudget.theBudget);
    return 0;
}

void spendDollar (dollars){
    vacationBudget.theBudget-=dollars;
}
void chargeEuros (euros){
    vacationBudget.euroTransaction=euros*vacationBudget.exchangeRate;
    vacationBudget.theBudget-=vacationBudget.euroTransaction;

}
```

HI GUYS! I am trying to learn objective C from "objective C for dummies" so I had a few questions. I was confused about 2-3 things- Hope you can help :D Thanks in advance

if you guys could explain in "NOOB" language that will be awesome.

1. Why do I need function prototypes for the functions that are written at the bottom? If executions starts in main won't the value just get transferred to the function without prototype?
   ERROR GIVEN- Conflicting types for charged euros and spend dollar
2. ABOVE IN CODE!
3. Also in the code printed in the book! For the 2 function down below it says that it should be double dollars and double euros for parameters. I was wondering why do I have to declare double again. Did not have to do that in python.( I know a bit of python)

Comment: FYI - none of the posted code is Objective-C code, it's basic C code.

Comment: Apart from the `#import` and `NSString`s.

Comment: @rmaddy I do not know obj c and C. I am studying for it from "obj-c for dummies". Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Because otherwise, at the time of calling, the compiler doesn't know what type the function returns, or what type(s) of argument(s) it accepts, and it needs to.
2. Presuming you're referring to the "implicit declaration" error, this just follows from (1), you get it because you tried to call a function before declaring it with a prototype, or by defining the function first.
3. C isn't Python. The compiler needs to know what type each argument is, because different types are represented differently. An `int` might need 4 bytes, and a `double` might need 8, for instance. This is pretty important information when deciding exactly what you need to pass to a function.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I updated 2nd qs for you!

Comment: I don't see any questions in the code.

Comment: Okk thank you! Everything is clear. Last thing. If we write double or int when it comes to function parameters. Why don't we also write double or int in the parameter when calling the function?

Comment: Because you already told the compiler what type your variable is when you defined it, e.g. `double numberDollars=100;`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I cannot accept your answer for another 4 min but I will do it ASAP. Could you not vote down my qs as I will not be able to ask if I get a few of them!

Comment: Asking better questions will help you avoid down votes, e.g. not doing things like "2. ABOVE IN CODE!", and just writing your question plainly and succinctly instead.

Comment: OK. will do next time! :)